# Converting user input to DateTime value

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have some user input - for example 150715 - it is supposed to be a date, but I have to change the format of `int` to `datetime -format yyMMdd`.

I have tried something like this:

```
$input = Read-Host "Get number (date)"
$input
$input_toDate = [datetime]$input -format yyMMdd
```

It doesn't work.

Is it possible to create this?

```
$input_toDate_up = ($input_toDate).AddDays(5) -Format yyMMdd
```

Comment: User input is `[string]` (unless you cast it to something else).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$input = Read-Host "Get number (date)"
$format = "yyMMdd"
$input_toDate_up = [DateTime]::ParseExact($input, $format, $null).AddDays(5).ToString($format)
$input_toDate_up
```

Input: `150715`, output: `150720`.

See [DateTime.ParseExact reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more info.